# Uniqueness and finite propagation with energy method use time derivative differently

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

The stack exchange solutions of

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172172/finite-speed-of-propagation-of-wave-equation

[Use energy method prove wave equation has a unique of solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197145/use-energy-method-prove-wave-equation-has-a-unique-of-solution)

use different definitions of $E'(t)$, where in one case the boundary term is missing.

I am following

(Graduate Studies in Mathematics, V. 19 GSM_19) Lawrence C. Evans-Partial Differential Equations-American Mathematical Society (1998)

and in that book, the reasoning to discard the boundary term given the conditions that $w_t=w=0$ on the boundary are:

[image: Evans explains why $u_t$ must be zero, but not $u_x$]

But there is no explanation of why $\nabla w$ should be zero on the boundary in order to make the integral of the energy over the boundary zero.